# best approach for storing images

Tags: database, optimization, storage

I am working on a .NET web application. The application has a separate database (SQL Server 2012) for storing and retrieving images. we have functionality in an application where multiple scanned documents are attached and stored in a database against each process. The daily increase in the size of this document DB is about 9 GB. I am stuck with the handling of this huge document DB. I am looking for the following questions

1. Should we use SQL Server database or Mongo DB or any other database for this scenario?
2. What should we do to better storing these daily increasing images, should we use any partitioning technique or any archiving technique, or any file system management technique.
3. what are the best practices for managing such huge images databases?
4. how to control its size limit, either we should apply any compression technique?
5. The system is mainly used for inserting documents and these documents are accessed rarely.
6. how can we optimize its storage?

Comment: The typical first question is, do you really need to store images into your database? What if you just store links / paths? File / web server is usually significantly cheaper and simpler than database. Also not sure do you store images or documents, but same rules apply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)